# WARN/ActivityManager(5038): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

From one application I am (broadcast) sending an intent to a broadcastreceiver of another one. I am getting the error:

```
WARN/ActivityManager(5038): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission
```

Comment: I posted the question just to describe the solution that I found: maybe saving another person's time: the problem was in the manifest file of the application where the BroadcastReceiver was defined: android:exported  should be defined as true

Comment: Thanks, Herschel- if you could post this as an answer to your question (instead of a comment) and mark it as correct in 24 hours, that would help others see that this question has been answered.

Comment: @Herschel, please answer your own question so that this does not turn up in unanswered questions lists.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add permission under your manifest file add these

```
<receiver android:name=".YourBroadCastReceiverName" android:exported="true"></receiver>
```

Comment: Same problem when I was trying to debug a service on my real device. adding 'android:exported="true" to service tag in AndroidManifest.xml solved the problem. Thanks for the tip though. Saved me hours of headache.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add android:exported="true" to the activity that will be invoked by the intent. Adding it to the receiver, as suggested by another answer, did not work for me, but adding it to the activity did.

Answer (score 1):

Herschel said: " the problem was in the manifest file of the application where the BroadcastReceiver was defined: android:exported should be defined as true"