# Permission Denied checkComponentPermission owninguid Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am new to android development so pardon me for any silly questions. I know that my question has some similar results for eg. [WARN/ActivityManager(5038): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984583/warn-activitymanager5038-permission-denied-checkcomponentpermission).

However, my case is somewhat different. I am currently using Unity and Prime31's social plugin for android. Posted to facebook successfully but however, when I was testing the link on my post, facebook crashes and the following is what I saw on the logcat. The link is just a testing link to google.com.

```
Permission Denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=12345
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=com.facebook.application.3456789087654 dat=http://google.com/ flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.company.app/com.prime31.FacebookProxyActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{2c39d4d8 4386:com.facebook.katana/10023 (pid=4836, uid=10023) not exported from uid 10014
```

I know that some one of the answer given is to add android:export but i am not sure how or where to add it. I tried adding it all over the place in my androidmanifest but to no avail.

Hope someone can enlighten me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in an edit. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved it by adding the activity `<activity android:name="com.facebook.katana" android:exported="true"></activity>`