# App wont build on non 4.4 devices after updating google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I just updated my google play services lib to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
```

I have the following within my build.gradle file (compile SDK version will be updated next; I'm working on a huge update with an app)

```
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17"
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

Everytime I build the app on any non-nexus device, I see the app install, but it wont open (no ANR; it just closes).

Here's some of my output that I *think* might be causing the issue:

```
02-14 19:46:19.608    2286-2816/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10134


I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.xxx.xxx (pid 23606) (adj 0) has died.
E/Launcher﹕ Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
```

Comment: so the app builds but doesn't run. have you tried the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984583/warn-activitymanager5038-permission-denied-checkcomponentpermission

Comment: Yes, I saw that and have tried the solutions, none of which worked.

Comment: is your application trying to open an activity that's in another app, in which case the other app would need the exported="true" in the manifest.

Comment: Nope, it's not trying to do that.  And exported=true is in the manifest.

Comment: could you post more of your logcat?

Comment: Yep, here you go: https://gist.github.com/whitneyimura/9009296

Comment: That's a lot of logcat... unfortunately i don't see anything in there that helps either. this is a quandary.

Comment: Same here!!  I can't figure out why this is happening...BUT, I do know that the only difference between this logcat and the output I get on successful builds (on 4.4 devices) are the lines that I pasted in my original question.

Comment: Looks like there are fairly new updates in Android SDK for Google Play Services (rev 15) and Google Repository (rev 6).  Have you installed these?

Comment: Yes, both of those are installed (installed this morning).  Now also getting after updating those: A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 30513 (AsyncTask #1)

Comment: If you downgrade Google Play Services version in build.gradle does it work?

Comment: Correction:  yes, I downgraded play services, restarted android studio, and it's building now. Any idea why this is happening, and what I can do to upgrade my GPS version?

Comment: Not sure why.  You could try upgrading again, maybe it was a build fluke last time with old libraries.  I'd also suggest trying to build on command line with `gradlew clean installDebug`, which would eliminate potential Android Studio issues.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using most recent Android Gradle plugin - `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+`

Comment: okay, great.  I'll try that. Thanks a bunch!!  Basically im in the middle of upgrading our google play services, build tools, support tools, gradle versions, build/compile target sdks...So upgrading gradle needs to happen eventually anyway.

Comment: Also, if you add your "fix" below, I can one-up it.

Comment: @WhitneyImura Cool, let me know how it goes.  Just added summary of above comments as an answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've one-uped your answer.  Interestingly, after building fine a couple of times (after changing gradle versions), it broke again, but now with: "local path doesn't exist". It's never ending, i swear lol!

Comment: Also, don't forget to sync gradle file changes in Android Studio, especially when changing dependencies.  That's bitten me a few times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would first try downgrading Google Play Services version in `build.gradle` and see if the app still works with the old version.

Then, make sure you update your Android SDK for newest versions of Google Play Services and Google Repository, and try the upgrade again.

I'd also suggest using the most recent version of the Android Gradle plugin in your `build.gradle` (e.g., `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0`)

Finally, I'd also suggest trying to build and install on the command line with `gradlew clean installDebug` to eliminate potential issues with Android Studio (note that you'll need to launch your main Activity manually, or via ADB command `adb shell am start -n com.xxxx.xxxx/.YourMainActivity`, as `installDebug` won't automatically start the activity).

Answer (score 3):

Although the above all helped, after running into even more hurdles, I realized that the app was not building on non-4.4 devices because the support libs (renderscript, in my case) have a bug (and therefore, no backwards compatibility).