# Permission denied, but nothing fails

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

Every time a i   startActivityForResult() , I get this line in logcat:

`07-30 00:18:07.013: W/ActivityManager(2889): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10095`

But nothing actually fails, i don't get  exceptions, everything works as it should.
I don't know what should i do about it, or if this can cause problems on other devices.

Here is the full code for the intent that i use:

```
// Determine Uri of camera image to save.
final File sdImageMainDirectory = getTempFile();
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

// Camera.
final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
    final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
    intent.setPackage(packageName);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    cameraIntents.add(intent);
}

// Filesystem.
final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

// Chooser of filesystem options.
final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

// Add the camera options.
chooserIntent
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);`
```

Why is this happening and what can i do against it, how can i find out why do i get this message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WARN/ActivityManager(5038): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984583/warn-activitymanager5038-permission-denied-checkcomponentpermission)

Comment: I looked at that question but it didn't answer anything, also i don't know what is ".YourBroadCastReceiverName"

Comment: Well, there is an answer there, namely to add your BroadcastReceiver(s) to the manifest, if you're using any, and to set "export" to true for it/them. I may have jumped the gun in concluding that question applies to you, though. Are you using a BroadcastReceiver? If not, it could be something else you're using that needs to be registered in the manifest or maybe a permission you need to add. Did you notice when you started seeing the message? If you can pinpoint what code you added that resulted in the message starting to be generated, that should help you figure out how to resolve this.

Comment: I  don't use BroadcastReceiver. The message appears in logcat, right after startActivityForResult and before the list of available activities appear. The android specific code is pretty much all that i pasted in (+ the intent Receiver method). The software is written with libgdx, and i'm just adding an option to select pictures from gallery/camera, and it is invoked with a callback from the software when a picture is needed. I have permissions set for external read/write, i don't know what else is needed (Adding CAMERA permission didn't change anything.).

Comment: Do you know exactly which line of code generates that warning? If not, step through your code with a debugger or add exgtensive logging to determine exactly which line of code causes the error. I'm assuming that this is a side effect of the call to `queryIntentActivities()` that you use to build the list of `cameraIntents`

Comment: it seems that it happens after the message AndroidGraphics paused, so debugging won't work since i get this: AndroidGraphics(4524): waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing, Kill's my application by the intention list still pops up.

Comment: @Sufian No, as i remember i used a completely different approach as a workaround, But i don't really remember it anymore.

Comment: @MattMagyar ah. Would've been helpful for you and everyone if you had posted the solution. Lesson for the future, sadly :(

Comment: @Sufian there was no solution,I checked my git logs, i had to rewrite the android part of my application.